# How do I find the .max of an attribute value among a group of different Models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, max

everyone:  I am also open to just straight-up refactoring what I'm finding to be pretty repetitive, but to give a baseline of how it's working....

I have for every contact a Campaign, which has_many of three types of Models: Email, Call, and Letter.

When an Email (Call or Letter) has been executed for a specific contact, I have a Contact_Email(_or_Call_or_Letter) which belongs to both the Contact and the Model (Email_or_Call_or_Letter).

Each Contact_Email for example pairing has a :date_sent attribute.  So does each Contact_Call and Contact_Letter.

**How do I find the latest of all of them?**

Here is the code I wrote that can find the latest Email and my finding retyping similar code for Call and Letter, but then stuck on how to do a .max on all of them:

```
  def last_email(contact)
    #get campaign the contact belongs to
    @campaign = Campaign.find_by_id(contact.campaign_id)

    @last_email = ContactEmail.find(:last, 
                        :conditions => "contact_id = #{contact.id}",
                        :order => "date_sent DESC")

    @last_call = ContactCall.find(:last, 
                        :conditions => "contact_id = #{contact.id}",
                        :order => "date_sent DESC")

    @last_letter = ContactLetter.find(:last, 
                        :conditions => "contact_id = #{contact.id}",
                        :order => "date_sent DESC")

    # how do I get the latest of all of these to display?

    @email_template = Email.find_by_id(@last_email.email_id)

    if @last_email.nil?
      return "no email sent"
    else
      return @last_email.date_sent.to_s(:long) + link_to('email was sent', @email_template)
    end
  end
```

**Question 1:  With what I have, how can I find effectively @last_event given I can find the last Email, last Call, and last Letter for every contact?**

**Question 2:  How can I remove the repetitive code that I have to write for each Model?**

Comment: I believe you really should consider using single table inheritance. This will make your life much easier :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have `has_many` associations setup in `Contact` referring to the other models? Something like:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contact_emails
  has_many :contact_calls
  has_many :contact_letters
end
```

If so, you can then create a `last_event` method on the `Contact` model:

```
def latest_event
  [contact_emails, contact_calls, contact_letters].map do |assoc|
    assoc.first(:order => 'date_sent DESC')
  end.compact.sort_by { |e| e.date_sent }.last
end
```

---

### Handling `nil`

When using the `latest_event` method you will get `nil` if there are no associated records. There are a couple of ways you can workaround this. The first is to check for nil first with something like:

```
contact.latest_event && contact.latest_event.date_sent
```

On late versions of Rails/Ruby you can also use [`Object#try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#M000293) which will call the method if it exists:

```
contact.latest_event.try(:date_sent)
```

I prefer not to use this as it doesn't check for `nil` but only if the object can respond to a method. This has cause some interesting errors if you expect `nil` if the object is `nil` but are calling a method which `nil` itself responds to.

Finally, my preferred method for the simple case is to use the [`andand`](http://github.com/raganwald/andand) gem which provides `Object#andand`. This greatly shortens the safe case above and saves calling of `latest_event` multiple times:

```
contact.latest_event.andand.date_sent
```

#### `date_sent`, `nil` and You.

For your example usage of calling `to_s(:long)`, you could either use `&&` or `andand`:

```
contact.latest_event.andand.date_sent.andand.to_s(:long)
```

or

```
contact.latest_event && contact.latest_event.date_sent.to_s(:long)
```

The first is safer if `date_sent` itself may be `nil`. Without using [`andand`](http://github.com/raganwald/andand) this could be written as:

```
contact.latest_event &&
  contact.latest_event.date_sent &&
  contact.latest_event.date_sent.to_s(:long)
```

which is rather complex and unwieldily in my opinion. I would recommend looking into [`andand`](http://github.com/raganwald/andand)

Comment: this will only look at those contact_emails, contact_calls, and contact_letters that were actually created, right?  In which case, there won't be an instance of nil class, right?  That's what I get with the other approaches.  This is interesting, forgot about .map method...but never fully understood yet either...checking it out!

Comment: So I could then just call Contact.latest_event to get the actual event?  So attributes could apply to Contact.latest_event.date_sent?

Comment: Hi, well, I have a situation where there may be NO contact_emails, contact_calls, contact_letters, so date_sent applies to a Nil class...how can I correct for that?  Thanks!

Comment: Hi Angela. I have added another second to my answer which covers how to handle `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

For question 1:

Just do

```
@last_event = [@last_letter, @last_email, @last_call].sort_by{|m| m.date_sent}.first
```

For question 2:

Well this is more interesting. This kind of depends on how exactly do your models look, but you might want to consider Single Table Inheritance for this type of scenario.

Comment: what happens if one of these instances (for example, @last_letter) has no value because no letter was ever sent?